# Loops for Dictionary key items

Tags: swift, loops, nested-loops

How can I fix the code so the loop would ask the question for each of the items in the dictionary?

*Edited the code to make what I am trying to do more clear. I want the code to stop and wait for the input BEFORE moving on to the next item in the dictionary.

```
   import Foundation
import UIKit



var squad = [1:"Arsh", 2:"Arbab", 3:"Ayush", 4:"KC", 5:"Jaski", 6:"Gunny", 7:"Harsh", 8:"Nagib", 9:"Rithin", 10:"Gursh", 11:"Sonny"]
let coming = "Yes"

let notComing = "No"

var attendees = [String]()

for ( key , person) in squad {
     // key == 1

//   key = counter

    // repeat {

    print("Are you attending \(person)?")
    let response = readLine()
        print(response as Any)

        if response == coming {
             attendees.append(person)
        }

        else if response == notComing {
            print("Sorry to hear that")
        }

        else {
            print("Invalid Input")
        }


       // }  while key <= 11

        // key += 1
    }




print(attendees)
print(attendees.count)
```

Comment: You're repeating your question 11 times per number/person pair. You could probably just move the counter/loop entirely.

Comment: How do you mean, @Alexander?

Comment: You're already enumerating all `(key, person)` pairs in `squad`. So why do you do you need the `repeat` loop?

Comment: Well, instead of waiting for the input, Xcode executes the entire code for everyone, I edited the code a little bit to make it more clear. But I am still unable to stop Xcode from executing the entire code BEFORE getting input for the first item in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

To experiment keyboard input features like `readLine()`, create a project by choosing from Xcode menu :

**File > New > Project > macOS > Command Line Tool**

and run it in Xcode, the Debugging Console pane will work as a terminal. Here the code you're looking for :

```
import Foundation

var squad = [1:"Arsh", 2:"Arbab", 3:"Ayush", 4:"KC", 5:"Jaski", 6:"Gunny", 7:"Harsh", 8:"Nagib", 9:"Rithin", 10:"Gursh", 11:"Sonny"]

let coming = "yes"
let notComing = "no"

var attendees = [String]()
let array = squad.map {return ($0.key, $0.value)} // Turn the dictionary to an array of tuples
let sortedArray = array.sorted(by: {$0.0 < $1.0 }) // Sort the array by the first element of the tuple

// Ask the squad one by one
for ( _ , person) in sortedArray {

    print("Are you attending \(person)?")
    if let response = readLine() {
        //remove white spaces and all letters lowercased so that "Yes", "yes" and "YES" would all be accepted
        if response.lowercased().trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces) == coming {
            attendees.append(person)
        }

        else if response.lowercased().trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces) == notComing {
            print("Sorry to hear that")
        }

        else {
            print("Invalid Input")
        }
    }
}

print("attendees : \(attendees)")
print("attendees.count = \(attendees.count)")
```

Comment: Awesome, but I see that the terminal asks the question with random items, and not in an order. Is there a way to make the code run from items 1 to 11 in order?

Comment: Yes because you've chosen `squad` to be a dictionary, and dictionaries are unordered. To go through the elements of a collection one by one in order, it has to be an array.